# how to retrieve data from three table in codeigniter for complete view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am new in codeigniter and php. I have two table in my **DB** what i need to do is i want to retrieve the data from tables **user_details, user_comments**.

**id** of user_details is same as  **id_user** in user_comments.

i want display  some output on my views, as there is no condition like, i need all user list with **first_name, last_name from user_details** and **number of comment by user from comm_id** .

```
        public function user_details(){

        $query=$this->db->select('id, f_name, l_name')
                ->from('user_details');

            $array=array();

            foreach($query->result() as $row)
                 {
                    $id=$row->id;
                    $array['f_name']=$row->f_name;
                    $array['l_name']=$row->l_name;
                    $query1=$this->db->select('comments')
                    ->from('user_comments')
                    ->where('id_user',$id);
                    foreach($query1->result() as $row1){

                            $array['comments'] = COUNT($row->comments;


                    }


                 }


            return $array;


    }
```

i need help please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to run N+1 queries. You can get all necessary data in one go with a query

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.f_name, u.l_name, COUNT(c.id_user) comments_count
  FROM user_details u LEFT JOIN user_comments c
    ON u.id = c.id_user
 GROUP BY u.id, u.f_name, u.l_name
```

Sample output:

```
| id | f_name | l_name | comments_count |
|----|--------|--------|----------------|
|  1 |   John |    Doe |              4 |
|  2 |   Jane |    Doe |              2 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7e09/2)** demo

Recommended reading:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

---

In Codeigniter this translates to something along the lines of

```php
public function user_details() 
{
    $rows = $this->db
        ->select('u.id', 'u.f_name', 'u.l_name')
        ->select('COUNT(c.id_user) AS comments_count', FALSE)
        ->from('user_details AS u')
        ->join('user_comments AS c', 'u.id = c.id_user', 'left')
        ->group_by('u.id', 'u.f_name', 'u.l_name')
        ->get()
        ->result_array();

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sir..i am getting error "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: sorry to irritate you again, but it is throwing error in view for name i used **php echo $user['l_name'] ; **  comment count is working fine..Thank you